# php CODEIGNITER: insert parent_id automatically to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, hierarchical-data

so I have a web program to upload a TSV file that contains table like this :

```
------------------------------------------------
SANDI     PENDAPATAN                            
------------------------------------------------
4.1       PENDAPATAN BUNGA/BAGI HSL & OPR UTAMA 
410       PENDAPATAN BUNGA/BAGI HASIL           
4100      PENDAPATAN BUNGA PENEMPATAN DANA
4101      PEND BNG/DISKON SRT BERHARGA YG DIBELI
4102      PENDAPATAN BNG.DOKUMEN/FASILITAS
4103      PEND BNG/PREMI TAGIHAN DERIVATIF
417       PENDAPATAN OPERASI UTAMA SYARIAH
4170      PENDAPATAN MARGIN MURABAHAH
4171      PENDAPATAN SALAM PARALEL
4172      PENDAPATAN ISTISHNA PARALEL
4173      PENDAPATAN BERSIH SEWA IJARAH
```

now take a look to the field "**sandi**" you can see the IDs are hierarchical-sorted.

```
4.1  => as a parent
410 and 417 => as a child of 4.1
4100-4103 => as a sub child of 410
4170-4172 => as a sub child of 417
```

I want process those flat data to be a tree data like this:

```
4.1 PENDAPATAN BUNGA/BAGI HSL & OPR UTAMA 
    410 PENDAPATAN BUNGA/BAGI HASIL           
        4100 PENDAPATAN BUNGA PENEMPATAN DANA
        4101 PEND BNG/DISKON SRT BERHARGA YG DIBELI
        4102 PENDAPATAN BNG.DOKUMEN/FASILITAS
        4103 PEND BNG/PREMI TAGIHAN DERIVATIF
```

This is the example of table structure to save the records :

```
COLUMN NAME        DATA TYPE 
------------------------------------
id_detail          int
sandi              varchar
pendapatan         varchar
parent_id          int
```

I have already searched about hierarchy data, parent and child etc. But I didnt found what I need. The question is:
**How to insert a field "parent_id" automatically based of the IDs on "sandi"  with looping PHP?**

Example:

```
id_detail  sandi         pendapatan                              parent_id
1          4.1           PENDAPATAN BUNGA/BAGI HSL & OPR         0
2          410           PENDAPATAN BUNGA/BAGI HASIL             1
3          4100          PENDAPATAN BUNGA PENEMPATAN DANA        2
4          4101          PEND BNG/DISKON SRT BERHARGA YG DIBELI  2
```

please help me, with a PHP CodeIgniter syntax.. thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Based on your detailed description of your question (although you didn't try anything), i'll show you how to accomplish things like that in CodeIgniter

first you need a controller

```
class ImportTSV extends CI_Controller
{

    public function import()
    {
        $this->load->model("ImportTSV_Model");
        $this->ImportTSV_Model->import();

    }
}
```

and a Model which contains the model it self and a Class for your Data Objects

```
class ImportTSV_Model extends CI_Model
{

    private $strFile = "data.tsv";
    private $masterNodeId = "41";
    private $arrDataObjects = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->prepareDataFromFile();
    }


    public function import()
    {
        $objMasterNode = $this->arrDataObjects[$this->masterNodeId];
        $this->save($objMasterNode);
    }

    private function save($objNode)
    {
        $arrInsertToDbData = array(
            "sandi" => $objNode->sandi,
            "pendapatan" => $objNode->pendapatan,
            "parent_id" => $objNode->mysqlParentId
        );

        $this->db->insert("your_table", $arrInsertToDbData);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();

        if (count($objNode->arrChilds) > 0)
        {
            foreach($objNode->arrChilds AS  $objNode)
            {
                $objNode->mysqlParentId = $id;
                $this->save($objNode);
            }
        }
    }

    private function prepareDataFromFile()
    {
        $file = FCPATH."assets/".$this->strFile;

        $objFile = new SplFileObject($file);
        while(!$objFile->eof())
        {
            $line = $objFile->fgets();
            $arrDataPerLine = explode("\t",$line);

            $objTSVData = new TSVData_Object;
            $objTSVData->prepareDataFromLine($arrDataPerLine);
            $this->arrDataObjects[$objTSVData->formattedSandi] = $objTSVData;
        }

        foreach($this->arrDataObjects AS $objItem)
        {
            //set parent ID
            $parent = substr($objItem->formattedSandi,0,-1);
            if (isset($this->arrDataObjects[$parent]))  $this->arrDataObjects[$parent]->addChild($objItem);

        }
    }
}


class TSVData_Object
{
    public $sandi;
    public $pendapatan;
    public $formattedSandi;
    public $mysqlParentId = 0;
    public $arrChildObjects = array();


    public function prepareDataFromLine($arrLine)
    {
        $this->sandi = $arrLine[0];
        $this->pendapatan = $arrLine[1];
        $this->formattedSandi = str_replace(".","",$this->sandi);
    }

    public function addChild(TSVData_Object $objItem)
    {
        $this->arrChildObjects[] = $objItem;
    }
}
```

i assumed your file is in the directory FCPATH."assets/".